# 'For' loop followed by an 'if' statement into 'for' loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, modulo

I'm trying to solve a puzzle on hackerrank (the Sherlock and Queries puzzle - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-queries). After working on it for a while, I started digging around on the internet for some help. I found one post here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58095/sherlock-and-queries-challenge?newreg=0bf47176275d428dbdfa0c6a4bc86f07 that confused me. It looks as if he changes this

```
for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
     if (j % B[i] == 0)
       ...
}
```

into this

```
for (int j = B[i] - 1; j < N; j += B[i]) {
     ...
}
```

Can someone please explain how these two are equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `B[i]` is an integer >= 2, the two snippets would be equivalent only if the second would be :

```
for (int j = 0; j < N; j += B[i]) {

}
```

Thus `j` would iterate over all the values that are divisible by `B[i]`, which are exactly the values of `j` for which the condition in the first loop is true.

If `j` is initialized to `B[i]-1`, `j%B[i]` is never 0, so the second loop is not equivalent to the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

The two are not equal.

The right equivalent for the first form that comes close to the second form would be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < N; j += B[i]) {
     ...
}
```

The first form lets `j` go from 0 to N and chooses only to act when `j` is dividable by `B[i]` (without a rest value). The second form gets the same result, by letting `j` go to `B[i] * 0, B[i] * 1, B[i] * 2.....N`. If you think about it, only multiples of B[i] are dividable by B[i] (without a rest value).